# problem with continuous motion using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to get my character to move as long as the key is pressed but so far it moves once per single press and the key needs to be released for him to move again.

I've tried using the pygame.key.get_pressed() as shown and I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

```py
def keyPressed(input_key):
    keysPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keysPressed[input_key]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
...

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if keyPressed(pygame.K_LEFT) and x > vel:
            x -= vel
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) in the application loop rather than the main loop. The event loop is only executed when an event occurs (like `pygame.KEYDOWN`). But the application loop is executed in every frame.
The typical use for `pygame.key.get_pressed()` may look as follows:

```py
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    #<---| Indentation

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < width-vel:
        x += vel

    # [...]
```

Comment: thank you for answering, I have tried doing it exactly as you've written down but it still doesn't work. maybe it's something to do with Pycharm or a version of pygame..? I'm at a loss.

Comment: @Brandy Then you've another bug elsewhere. Did you respect the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)?

Comment: That was it! thank you! I thought I needed to put the keypress within the event.get() for some reason, that was dumb of me.